# How to show price of product on non shop page

Tags: product, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I would like to show the prices of all available products for users on a non-shop page.

If I look into the code of the display of products on the shop page it gives me this line:

```
<span t-if="product.price" t-esc="product.price" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': website.currency_id}"/>
```

On my other page I call my products using this code:

```
<t t-set="products" t-value="request.env['product.template'].search([])"/>
<t t-foreach="products" t-as="product_template">
    <span t-if="product_template.price" t-esc="product_template.price" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': website.currency_id}"/>
</t>
```

This doesn't display the products price. If I remove the `t-if="product_template.price"` it displays `0.00 $`. So the `product_template.price` is not set?

Should I call something like `<t t-call="website_sale"/>` or something similar?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**:

On other product pages the classes `js_sale` `oe_website_sale` `oe_product` `oe_product_price` `oe_price_h4` are called. So I've tried this:

```
<div id="wrap" class="js_sale">
  <div class="oe_website_sale">
        <t t-set="products" t-value="request.env['product.product'].search([['id', '=', 135]])"/>
        <div t-foreach="products" t-as="product" class="oe_product oe_grid">
          <div class="oe_product_price product_price">
             <h4 class="oe_price_h4">
                <span t-esc="product.price"/>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

But this still doesn't work. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "non shop" page? No template? 
Then you cannot use the qweb language as far as I know.

What about using something like:

```
<field name="product.price" ... />
```